# How to use itextsharp to remove the security of a PDF and water watermark the pdf

Tags: c#

I urgently need to add watermark on different types of pdf including normal pdf, digitally signed pdf and password prodected pdf programatically using C#. I can watermark normal pdf and some pdf that are digitally signed using the code below but, it doesn't works for other pdfs that are digitally signed and security protected. Can anyone tell me how to remove the security of a pdf using **itextsharp** so that they can be watermarked.

The following code can add watermark on normal pdf that are not security protected but cannot watermark on the security protected pdf.

```
public void AddWatermarkText(string sourceFile, string outputFile,
string watermarkText, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont watermarkFont, float
watermarkFontSize, iTextSharp.text.Color watermarkFontColor, float
watermarkFontOpacity, float watermarkRotation)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = null;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfGState gstate = null;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte underContent = null;
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = null;

        int pageCount = 0;
        try
        {
                           {
                 reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourceFile);
                rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
                stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new System.IO.FileStream(outputFile, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew), '\0', true);

                if (watermarkFont == null)
                {
                    watermarkFont =iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.HELVETICA,iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CP1252,iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                }
                if (watermarkFontColor == null)
                {
                    watermarkFontColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE;
                }
                gstate = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfGState();
                gstate.FillOpacity = watermarkFontOpacity;
                gstate.StrokeOpacity = watermarkFontOpacity;
                pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    underContent = stamper.GetUnderContent(i); 
                    //_with1 = underContent;
                    underContent.SaveState();
                    underContent.SetGState(gstate);
                    underContent.SetColorFill(watermarkFontColor);
                    underContent.BeginText();
                    underContent.SetFontAndSize(watermarkFont,watermarkFontSize);
                    underContent.SetTextMatrix(30, 30);

underContent.ShowTextAligned(iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER,watermarkText,rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, watermarkRotation);
                    underContent.EndText();
                    underContent.RestoreState();
                }
            }
          stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of security protection is that you can't modify the document.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader allows you to specify an Owner Password as an argument if you know the password.  There are also numerous online web sites that you can use to remove the security settings of a PDF file if you LEGALLY have the right to do so.  iTextSharp cannot remove security setttings.

Comment: In my case, I cannot sepcify an Owner Passowrd as an argument. So, I need to go for other alternatives. Can you suggest me some sites that would be helpful for me to apply in my code to remove the security settings. Also can you please suggest me the best option for me. (I legally have right to alter the security settings)

Comment: If you cannot control where the PDF documents are coming from, you could use the tool here ([link]http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/pdfcrypt) and run the executable on the server through .net. It will flatten any form files (wont' be fillable anymore). The command arguments for decryption are: pdfcrypt input_file.pdf output_file.pdf decrypt "" making sure you use a pair of double quotes for the unknown password.

Comment: I decrypted my pdf using(http://rubypdf.appspot.com/pdfdecrypt.html)online and tried to watermark on this decrypted pdf using my code above. But still my code is not able to watermark the pdf. So, can you suggest me any idea why some pdf could be watermarked easily using the code above even if they are digitally signed, At the same time some couldn't be watermarked even if they are decrypted using the above software. what do u think would be the best option left for me in this scenario.